# How can i change the volume type affected when the user adjusts the volume manually?

Tags: android, audio, media, volume

I play short sounds in my app. about 0.5s, and I can imagine the user might want to adjust the volume of their playback.  But they are so short that by the time you press the volume op or down buttons, the sound is over and you are changing ringtone volume and not media volume.

Is there a way to make it so the user's volume input specificaly affects media volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity set this

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
     }
```